# How do I split a string in function in C?

Tags: c, strtok

I need a function that split a string in c, i write the code and I checked it, I didn't get any errors or warnings, the code is :

```
int main()
{
   cutString("any#any#any5") ;
    return 0;
}
void cutString(char  query[2000]) {
    char * cut ;
    cut = strtok(query , "#") ;
printf("%s" , cut);

}
```

But when I compile the program the compiler get stuck, without showing any output.
[This is a picture for run screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUy1Y.png)

Comment: Both answers to this question omited one important fact: 'strtok' can not be used on constant strings because the function change it internally. If someone need tested working example  please feel free to contact me by mail.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the usage of `strtok()`. According to the [Linux Man Page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), on the first invocation of the function, you should specify the string to parse as first argument, while in each subsequent call you should specify `NULL`.

In fact, a sequence of calls on the same string maintains a pointer to the next character to process. If you want to check if no more tokens are found, just look at the return value (it'd be `NULL` in that case).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should read about the usage of [strtok()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

Please keep in mind you **can't** use strtok() on a string literal, since it will attempt to modify it which will cause undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char toCut[100] = "to#cut#this";
    cutString(toCut);
    return 0;
}
void cutString(char* query) {
    char* cut ;
    cut = strtok(query, "#"); // this first call returns a pointer to the first substring
    while(cut != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", cut);
        cut = strtok(NULL, "#"); // each call to strtok returns a pointer to the next substring
    }
}
```